# Why does jQuery UI's datepicker break with a dynamic DOM?

Tags: jquery-ui, dynamic-data

I'm working with a dynamic DOM here, and have called the jQuery UI datepicker to all inputs with a specific class name, in this case `.date`

It works great with the first, static, construct but when I clone it the event handlers don't seem to want to move over. I get the Firebug error:

> inst is undefined

I tried looking into jQuery's new `live()` function but couldn't combine the two. Any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ah, got it. Right after I append the HTML to the DOM I run this on all the inputs I'd like to have a datepicker pop up with. Datepicker adds a class to elements it has been attached to, so we can filter out existing inputs and only apply it to new ones.

`$('.date').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker();`

I hope this helps people as I was Googling for days and didn't find anything!

**You should also note that it would be faster to check for `input.date` in the new generated HTML by setting that as a context, rather than the whole page, as it will save time, due to this being a more efficient operation.**

Comment: Will, Thanks a lot! You saved a couple hours of my life :)

Comment: When using a dynamic DOM this solution didnt help me when I was (jquery) cloning table rows with events. My solution was to do $('.date').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();

Comment: David, what jQuery core and UI version are you using? This was for 1.3.2 and 1.7 respectively, and the solution has worked with other implementations. Whatever floats your boat though!

Comment: this helped me solve me problem no end. My issue was I'd added a class called `hasDatepicker` to my input, unrelated to Jquery ui. The Jquery ui code obviously checks for this class before applying the datepicker, which stops it working! Don't add a class called `hasDatepicker` to a input you want to actually add a datepicker too! it results in the error message `inst is undefined`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar Issue, I had multiple tables on a page and each had multiple datepickers, also on click of button "AddLine" it added a table row with dynamic HTML and datepicker.

I realized after a lot of search that my input date fields had no "id" defined they looked like this

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="mDate1" value="" size=8 >
```

jquery was pointing all the date fields values to the very first date field defined on page, the calendar would popup on all the date fields but the value of 1st date field would change, I made a change to the html like this

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="Date1" name="mDate1" value="" size=8 >
```

by adding a "id" and it started working, for the dynamic date fields I change the Id like this

```
var allColumns = $("#"+$tableId+" tr:last td"); 
        $(allColumns).each(function (i,val) {
            if($(val).find(":input").hasClass("datepicker")){
                $(val).find(":input").attr("id",newId+$(val).find(":input").attr("id"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the 'live' event to make it work with dynamic DOM. So, if the class for your datepicker inputs is 'date-input', following code will make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date-input').live('click', function() {
    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
        });
});
```

Comment: No. You're recreating a datepicker every time the input is clicked, which is not performant.

Comment: +1 for simple and works when had problems with other solution

Comment: Then I imagine you're the kind of programmer who doesn't take pride in his work.

Comment: I have improved this answer to avoid recreating the datepicker and is showing on fisrt click/focus

Answer (score 4):

This might be a little late, but all the suggestions above didn't work for me, I came up with an easy solution for this.

First, what is causing the problem:
JQuery assign datepicker to element id. if you are cloning element, then same id might be cloned as well. which jQuery doesn't like. You might end up with either receiving  null reference error or the date being assigned to first input field regardless which input field you click on.

Solution:

1) destroy datepicker
2) assign new unique ids to all input field
3) assign datepicker for each input

Make sure your input is something like this

```
<input type="text" name="ndate[]" id="date1" class="n1datepicker">
```

Before you clone, destroy datepicker

```
$('.n1datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
```

After you clone, add these lines as well

```
var i = 0;
$('.n1datepicker').each(function () {
    $(this).attr("id",'date' + i).datepicker();
    i++;
});
```

and the magic happens

Comment: You're doing more work than you need - destroying everything and recreating everything.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$j(id or class).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

It is working

Comment: You're not destroying the datepicker, though, which means you're essentially rebinding something each time that code is triggered. So instead of one datepicker, you'll have two (or it'll happen twice - not tested).

So yeah, it might look like it works, but it won't function optimally.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're doing in addition to setting datepickers on new elements, is rebinding everything to previously created elements which is going to take up memory. This might not be noticeable over short periods of time, but if the page never reloaded and you did this many times, you would notice a difference. It's generally considered good programming practice to look after memory :)

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery selectors:

```
$(".mydatepicker:not(.hasDatepicker)").datepicker()
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple instances of the jquery-ui library on the page will cause this error too. Removing redundant instances work for my case

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same symptom, in this caused by having a td containing element with the same id attribute as the input,

```
 <td id="fld_xyz"><input id="fld_xyz" class="date" /></td>
```

I know this isn't ideal anyway, but it's worth knowing that the datepicker component seems to be relying on the uniqueness of the id.

Comment: Yes. IDs are supposed to be unique. If you want to identify a multiple elements of the same class, then use the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. My situation ended up being I had another element with the same ID as the input with the datepicker.

Comment: I had the same issue - the div enclosing the input text field had the same ID as the text field. Removing the id on the div fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same issue... I am using [datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) plugin in my application.
Also using jquery's default datepicker too.  When ever I am invoking them both on document ready I am getting the error `inst is undefined`.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepickerCustom").datetimepicker();
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#MainForm").validationEngine('attach');
        ....
    });
```

So I changed the code to invoke before document ready like below:

```
    $(".datepickerCustom").datetimepicker();
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#MainForm").validationEngine('attach');
        ....
    });
```

Now every thing is working fine. No problems.

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work, it is because of the cloned id. You can completely remove datepicker like this:

```
$(selector).removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeAttr('id').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with data picker not working after a first call. I found an answer to my issue here:

http://www.stemkoski.com/problem-with-jquery-ui-datepicker-dynamic-dom/

I was cloning sections dynamically from template and inadvertently including the class that datepicker adds once its called:

```
hasDatepicker
```

I placed my first datepicker call after I clone the template and that did it. I then added a datepicker call after each instance of clone:

```
$(source).clone().appendTo(destination).find(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

After trying many of the answers here, this is what worked for me and is showing on the first click/focus

```
function vincularDatePickers() {
    $('.mostrar_calendario').live('click', function () {
        $(this).datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showOn: 'focus' }).focus();
    });
}
```

this needs that your input have the class 'mostrar_calendario'

live is for JQuery 1.3+ for newer versions you need to adapt this to "on"

See more about the difference here http://api.jquery.com/live/