# Weird jQuery date picker action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I declare a datepicker with live, seems to work as expected until you change the month. Then instead of going to the next or previous month it skips back to January 1900 if you press forward month and December 1899 if you press back month.

using

```
$('.datepicker').live('focus', function () {
  $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker();
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you link to an example page that demonstrates this?

Comment: An example of the condition _[is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/qXFpz/)_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a possible reason you are seeing the problem is, when you use focus to attach to the input, you are then destroying your datepicker and remaking one. However, when you click on your input, it runs, so destroys the datepicker, and shows one. However when you click next or previous, you will initially loose focus on the input, but the datepicker script will 'refocus' it and hence fires off the destroy and re-create a datepicker.

I assume you are using live to attach a datepicker to a dynamic input - you could always use [`$('.datepicker').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059107/why-does-jquery-uis-datepicker-break-with-a-dynamic-dom) call in your `success:......` callback of your ajax call, where I will assume, you are creating your new input. This will have the affect of adding a `.datepicker()` to any input item with the class `datepicker` which hasn't already had a `.datepicker()` added. *(An input which has had a `.datepicker()` added to it, will also have the class `hasDatePicker` added to it)*

---

An alternative method - keeping with the live call - which has pro's and con's

- **PRO**: you only need it once in your code - instead of placing it several times if you have several ajax calls which may add several dynamic inputs.
- **CON**: You are creating a much more resource hungry bit of code as it will run every time an input receives focus, instead of just applying the `.datepicker()` once.

So to keep with the live, you could do the following:

```
$('.datepicker').live('focus', function () {
    $(this).not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker();
});
```

*See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/qXFpz/2/)*

This will attach a `.datepicker()` to any input with the class `datepicker` which **hasn't** already got a `.datepicker()` attached *(class `hasDatePicker`)*, this should save you destroying and recreating all datepickers.

*This will do the same as @Andrew Whitaker's solution*

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce your example, and I logged to the console every time `focus` was being handled and it looked like twice for every click on the input.  I changed the event that `live` was handling to `focusin` and the problem goes away:

```
$('.datepicker').live('focusin', function () {
  $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker();
});
```

I'm still doing some digging to see what exactly is going on.

**Edit:** In the source for datepicker, there are several manual `focus()` calls, its probably one of these that's causing the problem.

Also, thanks to @Scoobler's comment below, the fix above won't work with jQuery 1.5, but seems to work for 1.4.4

Additionally, if your goal is to apply `datepickers` to elements added via AJAX, you might want to consider checking for existence of a datepicker and *then* apply the datepicker widget if it does not already exist:

```
$('.datepicker').live('focus', function () {
    if (!$(this).data("datepicker")) {
      $(this).datepicker();
    }
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work - for me at least - the first change works, ie its showing feb, click previous mounth shows jan, as expected, however the 2nd click on previous month will jump to nov 1899 _[see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/qXFpz/1/)_

Comment: @Scoobler: Thanks, I see the problem--It seems to occur only with jQuery 1.5, not with 1.44. Interesting...

Comment: +1, I have posted an answer to what I __think__ is happening because it was too long for a comment, but I agree, I think it will be due to loosing focus when clicking the calendar, then regaining it due to the datepicker script - odd how this occurs in the v1.5 and not v1.4.4....

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');    
$('.datepicker').removeClass("hasDatepicker").removeAttr('id');    
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
```

This will completely remove the datepicker and make a new one each time you click on the datepicker. This is mostly helpful for the datepicker on a dropdown. I also found this to be usefull for having multiple rows of items that have their own dates.

Answer (score 0):

For the jQuery 1.7+ this is a good solution when adding date inputs dynamically

```
$('.datepicker').on('focusin', function () {
    $(this).not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker();
});
```

Worked for me!