# putting datepicker() on dynamically created elements - JQuery/JQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have dynamically created textboxes, and I want each of them to be able to display a calendar on click. The code I am using is:

```
$(".datepicker_recurring_start" ).datepicker();
```

Which will only work on the first textbox, even though all my textboxes have a class called datepicker_recurring_start.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: When you say "dynamically created", do you mean with code-behind before the page loads or with javascript after the page loading? Because if the elements are added after the page loading, you'll need to rebind the calendar each time a new textbox is added.

Comment: I am loading it in the code-behind with PHP.

Comment: I think you might be getting confused, but then its hard to tell with the info you've supplied. So just to confirm, can you confirm what you mean by 'dynamically created textboxes' please.

Comment: If I am loading 'page one', php looks at the db to see how many date textboxes are in 'page one' and displays it. So when 'page one' loads, there will be 4 textboxes which need to load the datepicker(). 'page two' has 7 textboxes which need to load the datepicker() function.

Comment: If you have a problem with data picker not working after a first call, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16283547/1329910 Your problem may have to do with datepicker adding its own class: hasDatepicker

Answer (score 300, accepted):

here is the trick:

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker_recurring_start", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/98/)

The `$('...selector..').on('..event..', '...another-selector...', ...callback...);` syntax means:
Add a listener to `...selector..` (the `body` in our example) for the event `..event..` ('focus' in our example). For all the descendants of the matching nodes that matches the selector `...another-selector...` (`.datepicker_recurring_start` in our example) , apply the event handler `...callback...` (the inline function in our example)

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ and especially the section about "delegated events"

Comment: This is a solution that would work in any kind of dynamic appending. +1 to you.

Comment: Although it seems strange to me that you'd want to call `.datapicker()` every time the textbox gains focus - so you'd want to be careful with this approach (assuming I'm reading this right). However, I think you'd be OK with the `.datapicker()` because it will probably check if a datepicker is created before trying to recreate. With other code you might not have this grace.

Also, .on( is only introduced in JQuery 1.7 - so make sure you're using the correct version.

Comment: datepicker is clever enough to check if it is already created or not (all jQueryUI components by the way) if jQuery version is below 1.7 you can simply use **live**

Comment: @skafandri +1 - totally agree: however for a newbie, they might be tempted to use this design for other code which might not be so 'smart', which could quickly and exponentially eat-up your browser

Comment: actually, I always use this design, (directly inspired from the **singleton design pattern** even in my hand coded plugins I use it, if the plugin is called, I check first if is the first time (I use the **data** jQuery function to store that information)

Comment: I don't see this as a problem, my answer is about **adding datepicker on dynamically created elements** not about **cloned elements**...

Comment: You might want to add a filter `:not(.hasDatepicker)`

Comment: This is a simple and elegant solution. Exactly what I needed. +1

Comment: worked for me.. and probably i can use the same method on other elements too.. :)

Comment: +1 to you. I have been looking for this solution for a day already. Thank you!

Comment: in my case it is not working . i mean working with only the last element i have generated . mean if i have created 10 element it is working only with last element

Comment: It should work with all matched elements, can you post a demo to your non working script?

Comment: Beware of using jQuery.clone() within an area that includes a datepicker. If you do, add this to remove the hasDatepicker class AND the id datepicker adds to your input: .... find('input.hasDatepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeAttr('id');

Comment: @skafandri Thanks For the Help. Can We do this on Bootstrap Autocomplete?

Comment: worked but it opens calender when jquery validation fails coz of focus.

Comment: if you are looking for a solution on JQuery 1.3+ see my answer below, it also shows on the first click/focus

Comment: doen't it add multiple duplicate event handlers on same input

Comment: @ilyeskooli what if the element is not an input type. I wanted to add the date picker to span element which created by dynamically. This focus and other events not supporting that

Answer (score 50):

For me below jquery worked:

changing "body" to document

```
$(document).on('focus',".datepicker_recurring_start", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Thanks to [skafandri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308134/skafandri)

Note: make sure your id is different for each field

Comment: Correct - for me I have to use $(document) and not  $('body')   - Sort of the problem with small snippets of code.  I can get the example to work no problem, but and soon as I add in a bunch of my javascript into a fiddle this code no longer works for me.   Thanks to both though.

Answer (score 19):

Excellent answer by skafandri +1

This is just updated to check for hasDatepicker class.

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){

    if( $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker') === false )  {
        $(this).datepicker();
    }

});
```

Comment: Could that then be shortened to ```$('body').on('focus',".datepicker:not(.hasDatepicker)", function(){$(this).datepicker();});```?

Answer (score 13):

Make sure your element with the `.date-picker` class does NOT already have a `hasDatepicker` class. If it does, even an attempt to re-initialize with `$myDatepicker.datepicker();` will fail! Instead you need to do...

```
$myDatepicker.removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

Comment: Exactly right! Dynamically loaded elements ended up not being the issue for me, so this solution worked.

Answer (score 6):

You need to run the `.datepicker();` again after you've dynamically created the other textbox elements.

I would recommend doing so in the callback method of the call that is adding the elements to the DOM.

So lets say you're using the JQuery Load method to pull the elements from a source and load them into the DOM, you would do something like this:

```
$('#id_of_div_youre_dynamically_adding_to').load('ajax/get_textbox', function() {
  $(".datepicker_recurring_start" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: This does not always work in practice from my experience. Best case is to add unique IDs to your elements and use those IDs to reference them and apply the datepicker. Seems internally the plugin uses those selectors.

Answer (score 2):

This was what worked for me (using jquery datepicker):

```
$('body').on('focus', '.datepicker', function() {
 $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The new method for dynamic elements is [MutationsObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) .. The following example uses [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to use ( _.each ) function.

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;    

var observerjQueryPlugins = new MutationObserver(function (repeaterWrapper) {

    _.each(repeaterWrapper, function (repeaterItem, index) {

        var jq_nodes = $(repeaterItem.addedNodes);

        jq_nodes.each(function () {

            // Date Picker
            $(this).parents('.current-repeateritem-container').find('.element-datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd MM, yy",
                showAnim: "slideDown",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1
            });

        });

    });

});

observerjQueryPlugins.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: false,
    characterData: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('body').on('focus',".my_date_picker", function(){
            $(this).datepicker({
                minDate: new Date(),
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me. In my app, I'm adding the date range elements to the document using jquery and then applying datepicker to them. So none of the event solutions worked for some reason.

This is what finally worked:

```
$(document).on('changeDate',"#elementid", function(){
    alert('event fired');
});
```

Hope this helps someone because this set me back a bit.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the class .datepicker in a javascript function, to be able to dynamically change the input type

```
 $("#ddlDefault").addClass("datepicker");
 $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({ timepicker: false, format: 'd/m/Y', });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified @skafandri answer to avoid re-apply the `datepicker` constructor to all inputs with `.datepicker_recurring_start` class.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="cmd">add a datepicker</button>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$('#cmd').click(function() {
  var new_datepicker = $('<input type="text">').datepicker();
  $('#content').append('<br>a datepicker ').append(new_datepicker);
});
```

here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjdp/5Lpxnrh9/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on JQuery 1.3 and is showing on the first click/focus

```
function vincularDatePickers() {
    $('.mostrar_calendario').live('click', function () {
        $(this).datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showOn: 'focus' }).focus();
    });
}
```

this needs that your input have the class 'mostrar_calendario'

Live is for JQuery 1.3+ for newer versions you need to adapt this to "on"

See more about the difference here http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".datepicker_recurring_start" ).each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",
        yearRange: '2000:2012',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true
    });
});
```