# Plugin initialization on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, plugins, datepicker, jquery-selectors, initialization

I'm using this code to initialize a datepicker plugin on my input

```
$('.datepicker input').datepicker({
    ... (options)
});
```

This works fine if the input is already present on page load, but for dynamically added inputs this does not work.

I tried doing it this way instead which doesnt not work either.

```
$('body').datepicker({
    selector: '.datepicker input',
    ... (options)
});
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [putting datepicker() on dynamically created elements - JQuery/JQueryUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433154/putting-datepicker-on-dynamically-created-elements-jquery-jqueryui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer here: [putting datepicker() on dynamically created elements - JQuery/JQueryUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433154/putting-datepicker-on-dynamically-created-elements-jquery-jqueryui)

```
$('body').on('focus', '.datepicker input', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        ...
    });
});​
```