# Datepicker stops working on reloads/paging

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm having trouble combining paged results with datepicker inputs.  The results are loaded via `.post` that resets a table inside a div (simulated in the example below as a button click).

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qg921ct/1/) helps illustrate what is happening, but the actual content will not be as similar as that example (i.e. `.html( $(elem).html() )`).

Originally I had the `.done` function from the post run another `$(".dt").datepicker()` but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10433307/1618257) suggested the `.on('focus',...)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the class `'.hasDatepicker'` still exist on the input after changing the id. Because of the class datepicker won't reinit.

Removing the class before adding the html will solve your problem.

```
var dateHMTL = 'Date 1<input id="dt1" class="dt" /><br/>Date 2<input id="dt2" class="dt" /><br/>Date 3<input id="dt3" class="dt" /><br/>Date 4<input id="dt4" class="dt" /><br/>Date 5<input id="dt5" class="dt" />'
$(function () {
    $(document).on('focus', ".dt", function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#btn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dateHMTL = $("#theDIV").html();
        dateHMTL=dateHMTL.replace(/Date (\d+)/g,"Date 1$1");
        dateHMTL=dateHMTL.replace(/dt(\d+)/g,"dt1$1");
        dateHMTL=dateHMTL.replace(/hasDatepicker/g,"");
        $("#theDIV").html(dateHMTL);
    });

    $("#theDIV").html(dateHMTL)
});
```

Look this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4s2vk0z/1/)