# How to set jQuery datepicker format to dd-mm-year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have the following in my view:

```
<input type="text" name="Model.Date" value="@Model.DateOfAction.ToShortDateString()"  class="txtDate" readonly = "readonly" style = "width: 90px; padding: 0px;" />
```

I then have below jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.getElementsByClassName(".txtDate")).each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: new Date(),
        });
    });
});
```

But `"18th March 2016"` is coming up as `"3/18/2016"` and I was expecting this `"18-03-2016"`

How do I properly set my desired format of `"18-03-2016"` (day,month,year)?. Notice that I want the separator to be this `-` not `/`.

Comment: What does `@Model.DateOfAction.ToShortDateString()` return? A date in `d/m/y` format?

Comment: @SalmanA it returns "3/18/2016 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: Is this the value you see in the control _when the page loads_? Does it change back to desired format when you choose a date using datepicker?

Comment: @SalmanA "3/18/2016 12:00:00 AM" is the value when i set a breakpoint at DateOfAction. After the page has loaded, is see this "3/18/2016". And yes it changes to the desired format when i choose a date using the datepicker.

Comment: @StackTrace did one of the answers help you? If so you may want to mark one as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have not set the date format correctly. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/guhmmkcp/). Basically you have to set the `dateFormat` like below:

```
$(function() {
    $('.txtDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: new Date()
        });
  });
```

Comment: Did you check my fiddle. Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/guhmmkcp/). It's working fine for me.

Comment: yes, your fiddle works but for some reason its not working in my mvc 3 view. Its a partial view being rendered in a main view. The datepicker is in the partial view's html row which is being dynamically added to an html table in the main view at the click of a button.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433154/putting-datepicker-on-dynamically-created-elements-jquery-jqueryui). This might helps you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document.getElementsByClassName(".txtDate")).each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: new Date(),
        });});
});
```

Comment: You don't each i.e. simple `$(".txtDate").datepicker(` will do