# How to initialize a JQuery plugin for elements added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, spectrumjs

In this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/ug9gq5ha/6/), I have two `table.inner-table` elements which were added initially in the HTML. [Spectrum plugin](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) works fine for all of the `input.basic` elements, that is clicking the element opens the color picker window.

BUT this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/ug9gq5ha/8/)** initially has only one `table.inner-table` element in the HTML. When you click the button labelled Click, another `table.inner-table` is added. The problem is with both the `input.basic` elements in this newly added table. **Clicking them does not open the color picker window**.

I am suspecting because color picker is already initialized, so it is not working for dynamically added elements. In the JS, the plugin is initialized like this:

```
$(".basic").spectrum();
```

**The question is how do I make it work for dynamically added elements?**

***WHAT I TRIED:***

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433154/putting-datepicker-on-dynamically-created-elements-jquery-jqueryui#answer-10433307), and added the following to JS. Did not work =(

```
$('body').on('focus', '.basic', function() {
    $(this).spectrum({});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var table = $('.outer-table > tbody > tr:last').clone();
$(table).find('.sp-replacer').remove();
$('.outer-table > tbody').append(table);
$(".basic").spectrum({});
```

If you click button, it would re-initialize `$(".basic").spectrum({});`.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/ug9gq5ha/9/)