# jquery datepicker on a cloned form element

Tags: jquery, datepicker

**EDIT : I am able to get the date picker on cloned form element but when i select a date, the date is populated on the first div form element, rather than cloned form element**

I am having problems in displaying a datepicker on a cloned form element.

I have initialized a div (PopupReset div having a jsp form in it).

when a button clicked I am copying and displaying the content of PopupReset in another div called "Popup" as modal dialog.

```
<div id="PopupReset" style="display:none;">
<jsp:include page="Popup.jsp"></jsp:include>
</div>


<div id="Popup" style="display:none"></div>
```

datepicker in both divs look same when I looked at the source code.
But datepicker working on first div "PopupReset" where as it is not working modal dialog, which has copy of "PopupReset" html.

```
 <input type="text" name="enteredOn" size="10" maxlength="10" value="" id="_enteredOn" 
 class="enterDate hasDatepicker">

  jQuery( ".enterDate" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "focus",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: dateFormat(),
        yearRange: "1901:-0"

        });
```

i am having the form cloned due to some constraints on the requirements.

Please share any ideas on how to work this out.

I appreciate your help!

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the javascript-call to initialize the datepicker, but I guess the problem is that the second datepicker is created dynamically. In this case you have to adjust the javascript / jQuery e.g. like this:

```
$('body').on('click',".enterDate", function(){
 $(this).datepicker();
});​
```

This is called event-delegation: the click-event is bound to the body-element which delegates the click-event to all elements with the class "datepicker", even if those aren't present in the actual document but added later.

Update: Adjusted the class name to the class name of adjusted question.

Comment: I updated my question. I could see "hasDatePicker" class on the cloned form element BUT datepicker not funcitonal on the second div.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : I am able to get the date picker on cloned form element but when i select a date, the date is populated on the first div form element, rather than cloned form element**

```
$(".enterDate").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

worked for me.

reference : 
[Why does jQuery UI's datepicker break with a dynamic DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059107/why-does-jquery-uis-datepicker-break-with-a-dynamic-dom)

Thank you Kishore I upvoted your answer and Thank you matthia_h